React/Node.js: Email verification succeeds but login fails with "Bad Request" error
I'm building a React application with a Node.js backend, and I'm encountering issues with email verification and login. Here's the problem:

When a user clicks the email verification link, the verification appears to succeed (the verified status changes to true in the database).
However, when trying to log in after verification, I get a "Bad Request" error (HTTP 400).
3.The console shows: POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login 400 (Bad Request)
4.An AxiosError is thrown with the message "Request failed with status code 400"

Here's the relevant code:
Email Verification Component (/client/src/components/EmailVerification.jsx):

const EmailVerification = () => {
  const { token } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [verificationStatus, setVerificationStatus] = useState("Verifying...");

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyEmail = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/verify-email/${token}`
        );
        setVerificationStatus(response.data.msg);
        toast.success(response.data.msg);
        setTimeout(() => navigate("/login"), 3000);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setVerificationStatus("Email verification failed. Please try again.");
        toast.error("Email verification failed. Please try again.");
      }
    };

    verifyEmail();
  }, [token, navigate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{verificationStatus}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmailVerification;

Login Component (/client/src/pages/Login.jsx):
const Login = () => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth")) || ""
  );
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLoginSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let email = e.target.email.value;
    let password = e.target.password.value;

    if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
      const formData = {
        email,
        password,
      };
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login",
          formData
        );
        localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
        setToken(JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
        toast.success("Login successful");
        navigate("/dashboard");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.response && err.response.data) {
          const errorMessage = err.response.data.msg;
          switch (errorMessage) {
            case "Bad password":
              toast.error("Incorrect password. Please try again.");
              break;
            case "Username not found":
              toast.error("User does not exist.");
              break;
            case "Please verify your email before logging in":
              toast.error("Please verify your email before logging in.");
              break;
            default:
              toast.error(errorMessage);
          }
        } else {
          toast.error("An error occurred. Please try again.");
        }
      }
    } else {
      toast.error("Please fill all inputs");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token !== "") {
      toast.success("You are already logged in");
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [token, navigate]);


Server-side Email Verification (/server/controllers/userController.js):
// server/controllers/userController.js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/User");

const verifyEmail = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.params;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const user = await User.findById(decoded.userId);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "User not found" });
    }

    if (user.verified) {
      return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Email already verified" });
    }

    user.verified = true;
    await user.save();

    return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Email verified successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid or expired token" });
  }
};
module.exports = { verifyEmail };


Server-side login(/server/controllers/user.js):
const login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      msg: "Bad request. Please add email and password in the request body",
    });
  }

  try {
    let foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (foundUser) {
      const isMatch = await foundUser.comparePassword(password);
      if (isMatch) {
        if (!foundUser.verified) {
          return res
            .status(401)
            .json({ msg: "Please verify your email before logging in" });
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: foundUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: "30d",
        });
        return res.status(200).json({ msg: "User logged in", token });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Bad password" });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Username not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server error" });
  }
};

What I tried:
Integrated an email verification system which used a token.login system that has a functionality of validating users. Separated the verification emilVerify handler and the log in into separate files in serverside.
What I expected:
After clicking the email verification link, the user's verified status changes to true correctly in the database however the login is broken now.The user should be able to log in successfully after email verification.

Can you please show the details of this routing navigate("/login").
